# Rule of thumb for boost converter current usage

Tags: buck-boost

I have a sensor that requires 12V DC for 14 seconds. I only have a 6V source. The device pulls 6.2mA at 12V during the 14 seconds. If I use a boost converter to get to 12V should I assume >12.4mA usage during the 14 seconds ignoring the boost converter efficiency for the moment?

Comment: yes.................

Comment: If you *ignore the efficiency* then it will be exactly 12.4mA...

Comment: And, it may be significantly more than 12.4 mA as the boost converter gets into regulation (maybe 10 ms to 100 ms, ignoring inefficiency).

Comment: thanks this is very beneficial for my "back of the envelope" battery life estimate.

Comment: You can assume 12.4mA (ignoring efficiency) on the 12V side, but expect double that on the 6V side (ignoring efficiency).